# Questions about coding in Java which are run using another system's Main Method

Tags: java

I am new to Java so the object-oriented programming is proving to be difficult for me because I am used to structured programming. And what makes it harder for me is that, the Core System I am working with provides us a template that requires us to use the method in there in order for us to run custom scripts in their system. So I just imagine that the run method is my main method.

I have made a few scripts for doing Maintenance on accounts, Bulk Upload/Insert of data, Extracts, etc. and here's how I work on my dev environment.

1. I created projects and put all the java files in that project based on their purpose. For example, I created a Maintenance Project which contains 1 package and inside that package are my Maintenance java files. Note that these java files are not related to each other. I combined them with the thought that it will be easy for me to locate my maintenance script or my extract scripts because they are all in their respective project.

**Question 1 - Should I be doing it this way or should I create multiple package based on what the maintenance script is doing? eg. com.maintenance.accounts, com.maintenance.users...
OR should I just create a different project for each script?**

2. In some of my scripts, I created the functions inside it and I repeat this function in other scripts/projects. *But I am cleaning my mess up and want to do it the right way.*

**Question 2 - What I am planning is create a library and put my functions in there add the library in my projects. Am I doing it right? But what if I made some modifications in the library I made, should I have to re-link my library again?**

3. For each script, I create a log file by creating a .txt file and doing a CSV data in it. This is what I give to some of our staff so that they can review which data got affected, or which information got changed.

**Question 3 - Is this the proper way to log the script? Basically what the staff is wanting is a list of information which he can open in Excel to verify what the script has done.**

For reference, this is how the template looks in my scripts:

```
... //imports
public class TestJava {
CoreSystemType cType = null;

public static void runMethod(CoreSystemType cType) throws Exception {
    TestJava mainProgram = new TestJava(cType);
    mainProgram.activateScript();
}

private TestJava (CoreSystemType value) {
    cType = value;
}

//this is where I put all my logic
private void activateScript() throws Exception {   
    ...
}//activateScript
}//class
```

Comment: Please don't call .java-files scripts. They are not. Java is a compiled language, not an interpreted language. To your question. 1: What do you mean by "project"? A project is no construct within Java, I assume you are using Eclipse and/or IntelliJ and talk about those packages? If so, making one project for each "thing" your code does seems too much. I would go with the approach of subpackages, all in one project. You can make one uber-package, eg `com.yourCompanyName` and derive all other packages from there

Comment: 2: Hard to say without furhter knowledge. In general, it is always good to remember the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). 3: There are ready-to-use lgging frameworks out there (log4j and slf4j are two that come to my mind). I am no expert on them, but why don't you take a look  and find out whether they d what you want?

Comment: Thanks @Turing85 for your advice! And sorry about the naming conventions I used. I will keep that in mind. On your answers (1) I'm currently using NetBeans, but you are right, the project is the folder and currently I have 1 package for each of my project that houses all my java files for like maintenance codes. (2)Exactly! That's what I'm thinking of the DRY Principle. (3)I will definitely look it up! Thank you for your suggestions!